# Doctrine2 QueryBuilder that explicitely matches nothing

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, abstract-class, query-builder

I'm using Doctrine 2.4 and I have an abstract base class that contains a method like follows:

```
protected function getBaseQueryBuilder($type) {
    switch ($type) {
        case self::TYPE_1;
            return $this->em->createQueryBuilder()->...lots of clauses...;
        case self::TYPE_2;
            return $this->em->createQueryBuilder()->...lots of clauses...;
        /* many more types... */
        case self::TYPE_N;
            return /* want to return a query builder for the empty set */
    }
}
```

There are several sub-classes that inherit from this base class and each of them calls this method from several places.  Then they extend the returned query builders with additional class specific clauses before executing them.  However, in the case of `TYPE_N`, no rows must ever match.

One solution is of course to return null for `$type == TYPE_N` and have every caller check for `null` and then not execute anything if so.  But it would be much nicer if I could return a query builder that will never match anything and for which the query would never even hit the DB.  That would simplify the many caller sites a lot.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than returning null and checking for that you could create a `TypeNQueryBuilder` that extends the query builder so it keeps the interface but returns an custom `TypeNQuery` that has the null/empty results that you require.

<kbd>Acme\Doctrine\TypeNQuery</kbd>

```
use Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery;

class TypeNQuery extends AbstractQuery
{
    /**
     * Override __construct so it doesn't require EntityManager
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getResult()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getOneOrNullResult($hydrationMode = null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSingleScalarResult()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //.. add as necessary
    // getArrayResult()
    // getScalarResult()
    // getSingleResult()
}
```

<kbd>Acme\Doctrine\TypeNQueryBuilder</kbd>

```
user Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;

class TypeNQueryBuilder extends QueryBuilder
{
    /**
     * Override getQuery() so it returns your TypeNQuery
     */
    public function getQuery()
    {
        return new TypeNQuery();
    }
}
```

Then in your `getBaseQueryBuilder` call you can add the clauses or return your `TypeNQueryBuilder` depending on the type provided.

```
protected function getBaseQueryBuilder($type)
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

    switch ($type) {
        case self::TYPE_1:
            $queryBuilder
                ->yadaYadaYada(....)
            ;
            break;
        case self::TYPE_2:
            $queryBuilder
                ->yadaYadaYada(....)
            ;
            break;
        case self::TYPE_N:
            return new TypeNQueryBuilder($this->em);
    }

    return $queryBuilder;
}
```

With the interface being the same you would just be able to use..

```
$this
    ->getBaseQueryBuilder($type)
    ->andWhere(...)
    ->addOrderBy(...)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

.. and depending on the type given it will either build the query properly or just drop out at the last minute and return your `null` result.

Comment: I like this solution. It could even be extended to override `andWhere()`, `orderBy()`, etc to make these operations even cheaper. I will try to implement this and see how it goes.

Comment: I think most of the methods like `andWhere`, `innerJoin`, etc all do something and then call `add` so you could just override that to just return `$this` and cut out a lot of the work.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to do something like that? I would say you should not create an expensive `QueryBuilder` object, just so you can get `null` from it later on when you call `getResult()`...

I would suggest you redesign your solution, maybe by adding an additional method in between where you pull the `getBaseQueryBuilder` method and where you get the actual result from the query builder. For example something like:

```
protected function getBaseQueryBuilder($type) {
    switch ($type) {
        case self::TYPE_1;
            return $this->em->createQueryBuilder()->...lots of clauses...;
        case self::TYPE_2;
            return $this->em->createQueryBuilder()->...lots of clauses...;
        case self::TYPE_N;
            return null;
    }
}

protected function getResultFromBaseQueryBuilder() {
    $type = $this->getType(); // get your type
    $queryBuilder = $this->getBaseQueryBuilder($type);
    if( $queryBuilder === null ){
        return /* empty result set so for example null, [] or new ArrayCollection(); */
    }
    return $queryBuilder->getResult();
}
```

You could alternatively check for type directly inside that method:

```
protected function getBaseQueryBuilder($type) {
    switch ($type) {
        case self::TYPE_1;
            return $this->em->createQueryBuilder()->...lots of clauses...;
        case self::TYPE_2;
            return $this->em->createQueryBuilder()->...lots of clauses...;
    }
}

protected function getResultFromBaseQueryBuilder() {
    $type = $this->getType(); // get your type
    if( $type === self:TYPE_N ){
        return /* empty result set so for example null, [] or new ArrayCollection(); */
    }
    $queryBuilder = $this->getBaseQueryBuilder($type);
    return $queryBuilder->getResult();
}
```

In other words instead of making a common interface containing the `getBaseQueryBuilder` method rather make an interface that holds a method that returns the result. (I suggest you rather call the method `getResult` instead of `getResultFromBaseQueryBuilder` which I used just to clarify the example).

Comment: I understand that building an expensive object to return nothing from it at the end is wasteful. However, it looks to me as if your solution doesn't allow for what I described I need: Several sub-classes will obtain such a query builder and then add more clauses to it before it gets executed. I don't see how that's possible with your solution, since the query builder gets constructed and its query immediately executed. Where would sub-classes hook in?

Comment: Based on the little information you give me in your comment it is hard to give you an advise. You could for example make an `addClause` or `addExpression` method to your service, but I have the feeling that there might be better means of reaching your goal. Maybe you can ask another question where you add more specifics to explain your user case? You could also inside the sub classes check whether you get a `QueryBuilder` instance at all and simply ignore the cases where you have `TYPE_N` (so no `Querybuilder`, it doesn't make much sense to add clauses to a query that will never be executed).

Comment: The use case that I require was already described in the original question. So can you be more specific about what information is missing? And yes I could do the check in the sub-classes, as I already mention in the original question. The question is specifically about not doing that, since that would be a lot more code to write.

Comment: @jlh downvoting my answer doesn't motivate me to spend any more time in helping you.

Comment: I'm downvoting it because it does not work with the use case that I described in the original question. I think that's a fair reason, that's what the voting is for. I understand if you don't want to spend more time on this. I'm currently trying out qooplmao's solution.

Comment: If you would be more specific on this part: *"they extend the returned query builders with additional class specific clauses before executing them"* with some code examples, then someone could give a much better answer.